# 1 GB network connection colocation

Tags: internet

I'm a developer and new to network / servers. I need a dedicated server to host something. I want a 1Gb internet connection. I have have found a colocation provider that states I will get a Gigabit switch port. But could this be a shared port with other servers? How do I know if I'm guaranteed this bandwidth? What are some questions I need to ask the hosting provider about the network that I should know? And how do people check the speeds of providers?

Comment: What do you need 1 Gbps for? I spent years running the infrastructure team for one of the UK's top ten web sites (by pages served), and we never used anything like as much as 1Gbps of external Internet capacity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for and read their contract and SLA for the internet service, we can't answer this for you. You are likely guaranteed this speed to the other end of the link, but they can't guarantee that the other end of one of your TCP connections (or any intermediate nodes) can support 1 Gbit end-to-end.

You test speeds with things like speedtest.net, if you have a browser on the server you're hosting there, or you could measure speeds with whatever application you're actually hosting. Your provider should also be able to provide bandwidth-usage graphs as part of their monthly stats, or even a current dashboard perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

> I have have found a colocation provider that states I will get a Gigabit switch port. But could this be a shared port with other servers?

No, the **port on the switch** will be dedicated for your server and will run at 1 Gbs without any oversubscription.

What you effectively get depends on your SLA but the typical CoLo provider will have a network topology with other servers/customers also connected at  1 Gbs on the other ports of the same (24/48/? port) switch your server will be connected to. From that switch there will be (multiple) 10/40 Gbs uplinks to their network core and from there internet traffic will be routed over (multiple) smaller and 1/10/40/100 Gbs uplinks to a number backbone/transit providers, peering partners and internet exchanges.

The required and available capacity of those uplinks will only be a fraction of the throughput of all their 1 Gbs switch ports combined.

Some Co-Lo providers do guarantee the full 1 gigabit speeds between different servers hosted in the same datacenter, if that's relevant. But typically a 1 gigabit switch port does not imply that you get a guaranteed exclusive 1 Gbs uplink to the internet at large though.

The colo provider may give you a number for the oversubscription factor but regardless of that number, for a large part you get what you pay for.